# Duplicate rows in multi-table MySQL query

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

We have three tables, "cameras", "cameratypes", and "locations".

Here are each with sample data.

locations(location_id, user_id, contact1)

```
select * from locations;
+-------------+---------+--------------------+
| location_id | user_id | contact1           |
+-------------+---------+--------------------+
|          38 |      96 | Joe Blow           |
|          42 |      96 | Joe Blow           |
|          45 |     105 | Francis McLucky    |
|          50 |     113 | Ogre L'Bosch       |
|          53 |     113 | Ogre L'Bosch       |
+-------------+---------+--------------------+
```

cameratypes(cameratype_id, title)

```
select * from cameratypes;
+---------------+----------------+
| cameratype_id | title          |
+---------------+----------------+
|             1 | Pan Tilt Zoom  |
|             2 | Fixed          |
|             3 | Mobile         |
+---------------+----------------+
```

cameras(camera_id, cameratype_id, location_id, user_id)

```
select * from cameras
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------+
| camera_id | cameratype_id | location_id | user_id |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------+
|      4633 |             3 |          38 |      96 |
|      4637 |             3 |          38 |      96 |
|      4644 |             1 |          38 |      96 |
|      4962 |             1 |          45 |     105 |
|      4667 |             2 |          45 |     105 |
|      4681 |             2 |          50 |     113 |
|      4689 |             2 |          50 |     113 |
|      4684 |             2 |          50 |     113 |
|      4682 |             3 |          50 |     113 |
|      4691 |             2 |          53 |     113 |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------+
```

I am trying to join the tables into a report, where the output is a list of cameras, with the owner's name and camera type.

Yet, when I run my query, I get this result (which is basically multiplying the number of cameras for user 113 (he has five) by the number of camera locations he has (which is two).

My query is:

```
SELECT 
    loc.contact1 AS 'Camera Owner Name', 
    loc.location_id AS 'Location ID', 
    cam.camera_id AS 'Camera ID', 
    camtype.title AS 'Camera Type' 
FROM engine4_securonet_cameras AS cam 
LEFT JOIN engine4_securonet_locations AS loc ON cam.user_id = loc.user_id 
JOIN engine4_securonet_cameratypes AS camtype ON cam.cameratype_id = camtype.cameratype_id 
WHERE loc.user_id = 113 
ORDER BY cam.camera_id;
```

The result of the query is:

```
+-------------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
| Camera Owner Name | Location ID | Camera ID | Type   |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
| Alexis Neve       |          50 |      4681 | Fixed  |
| Alexis Neve       |          53 |      4681 | Fixed  |
| Alexis Neve       |          50 |      4682 | Mobile |
| Alexis Neve       |          53 |      4682 | Mobile |
| Alexis Neve       |          50 |      4684 | Fixed  |
| Alexis Neve       |          53 |      4684 | Fixed  |
| Alexis Neve       |          50 |      4689 | Fixed  |
| Alexis Neve       |          53 |      4689 | Fixed  |
| Alexis Neve       |          50 |      4691 | Fixed  |
| Alexis Neve       |          53 |      4691 | Fixed  |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I eliminate this duplication? Thanks *so* much in advance!

Comment: I can't see any duplication. What would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were joining all locations that an owner was associated to, not only the camera's location.

```
SELECT
  loc.contact1 as Owner,
  loc.location_id as "Location Id", 
  cam.camera_id AS "Camera ID", 
  camtype.title AS "Camera Type"
FROM cameras AS cam

LEFT JOIN locations AS loc 
       ON loc.location_id = cam.location_id
      AND cam.user_id = loc.user_id                                                            

JOIN cameratypes AS camtype 
  ON cam.cameratype_id = camtype.cameratype_id

WHERE loc.user_id = 113 
ORDER BY cam.camera_id;
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes total sense. Cheers.